# Cannot Select image file from external file browser with ckeditor4 but it works perfectly in ckeditor3

Tags: image, ckeditor

Hello to anyone who may be able to help with this.

I had been using Ckeditor3 and had created a simple custom image browser. It worked perfectly. I would click the image button and the dialog box would pop up and then I would click the browse server button. I searched the images and when I found one I wanted to use I clicked it the image browser would automatically close and the image would then show up in the image preview box in the image plugin dialog box.

Unfortunately the image plugin for ckeditor 3 has become incompatible with Internet Explorer 11. So I upgraded to the latest Ckeditor 4.

So now in ckeditor 4 I can still open the image dialog and click the image browser and browse my images but now when I select an image, although the image browser closes as it should the image is not being passed back to the plugins preview box or url field within the dialog box. It just remains blank. If i manually paste in an image url the image will show up in the preview box but no longer from the image browser anymore.

i have spent hours looking for a solution on google and am coming up empty, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you check if is a known issue when using a specific browser/os and/or a bug?

Comment: While ckeditor 3 worked fine for me in all browsers except IE11, the problem I am having now as described in my post that is happening in ckeditor 4 is happening in all major browsers, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE11. I was not able to find reference to my specific problem. It is a difficult problem to explain and search for with minimal text.

Comment: Also, ckeditor 3 still works perfectly in all browsers except IE11. If I switch between 3 and 4 right now , say using ckeditor 3 with chrome, it will work perfectly but when I switch to 4 it will not work.

Comment: Provide the instructions to reproduce the behaviour and open a ticket with the supplier also: if a product is not working your best bet is asking to the supplier. Here we can help but ask the supplier too.

Comment: FYI, ckeditor closed down its own support forums and said to use stack overflow with the hash tag ckeditor.

Comment: Ok. Now please post the steps to reproduce. Ckeditor is not a single page app with zero config: how you repro the behaviour? What if you change client? And with diffferent os?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

To fix the problem I had to change the code in the file browser as follows. I do not know why the first snipped works in ckeditor 3 but not 4.

```
function selectFile(fileUrl){
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(2, fileUrl);
}

Change to:

function selectFile(fileUrl){
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1, fileUrl);
}
```

But now everything is forking fine in CK editor 4.